# Findings components of acceleration in $\mathbf{r}(t) = \left(\sin(t),\cos (2t),t^2+2t\right)$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, physics

> The position vector of moving point at time $t$ is $\mathbf{r}(t) = \left(\sin(t),\cos (2t),t^2+2t\right)$. Find components of acceleration $\mathbf{a}$ in directions parallel to velocity vector $\mathbf{v}$ and perpendicular to plane of $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ at $t=0.$

I know the acceleration vector is the second derivative of the $\mathbf{r}$ vector, but how to proceed?

Comment: By "... perpendicular to plane $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ ..." is the problem asking for the component of $\mathbf{a}$ that is in the plane containing $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{v}?$

Comment: Aren't you able to compute this second derivative ? Please show us.

Comment: i have difficulty in understanding point of question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $$ \vec r = (\sin t, \cos 2t, t^2 + 2t)$$ $\Rightarrow \vec v = ( \cos t , -2 \sin 2t ,2t + 2)$  and $ \vec a = ( -\sin t , -4 \cos 2t , 2)$ which at $t = 0$ are $(1,0,0)$  and $( 0,-4,2)$ respectively.

Now,

1. Projection of $\vec a$ on $\vec v$ is $\cfrac{ \vec a \cdot \vec v}{|v|} $ and the component parallel to $\vec v$ is $\cfrac{ \vec a \cdot \vec v}{|v|} \hat v$
2. This part can be proceeded in the exact same way as the first part, you have replace  $ \vec v$ with the normal vector of the plane (as that is the vector parallel to which you have to obtain the components) which here is $ \vec v \times \vec r$

Comment: I think you mean $\vec{v}\times\vec{r},$ not $\vec{v}\times\vec{a}.$

Comment: can anyone explain what is going on

Comment: Which part @J.Deff ?

Comment: @J.Deff Ajay is basically determining a unit vector in the required direction. Then finding the projection of the acceleration vector onto that unit vector. The second part involves finding a unit normal vector to the plane, which can be done by taking the cross product between two vectors lying on the plane, then dividing by its own magnitude.

Comment: I have edited the part in which I thought you had the problem.

Comment: in first part shouldnot denominator by magnitude of $v^2$

Comment: and why had you separated two parts. as per question it seems both conditions has to be togethor

Comment: $ \hat v = \cfrac{\vec v}{|v|^2} $

Comment: are you using projection formula which states that projection of u onto v is $$ \frac{(|u| \cdot |v| ) v}{|v|^2}$$

Comment: what do you mean by "planes of r and v" ?I t doesnot seem clear to me.

Comment: Yes. How both question can be of same part? I mean how one can tell component which is parallel to $ \mathbf v$ AND perpendicular to plane of $ \mathbf v$ and $\mathbf r$, as in the latter case the component which is perpendicular to $\mathbf v$ is needed. So in short, if both part were of same question, it was intented to ask what is would be component of $\mathbf a$ which is perpendicular and parallel to $\mathbf v$.

Comment: Plane whose normal $\mathbf n$ lies along $ \mathbf r \times \mathbf v$

Answer (score 0):

$$\vec{r}(t)=(\sin t,\cos2t,t^2+2t)\Rightarrow \vec{r}(0)=(0,1,0)$$
$$\vec{v}(t)=(\cos t,-2\sin2t,2t+2)\Rightarrow \vec{v}(0)=(1,0,2)$$
$$\vec{a}(t)=(-\sin t,-4\cos2t,2)\Rightarrow \vec{a}(0)=(0,-4,2)$$
tangential acceleration is
$$a_T(t)=\vec{a}(t)\cdot\vec{T}(t)=\vec{a}(t)\cdot\dfrac{\vec{r'}(t)}{|\vec{r'}(t)|}=\vec{a}(t)\cdot\dfrac{\vec{v}(t)}{|\vec{v}(t)|}$$
then
$$a_T(0)=(0,-4,2)\cdot(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}},0,\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{5}})=\dfrac{4}{\sqrt{5}}$$